# Join tables with equal columns

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two tables `users` and `cars`, the `cars` has a column `owner` that is the `id` of an user and I need to join them. Both `users` and `cars` has a column called `name` and it's overriding. I want to keep both but with different names, like `car_name` and `user_name` on the return.

Here is how I'm doing:

```
$columns = [
    DB::raw('cars.name as car_name')
];

$cars = Cars::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'cars.owner')->get($columns);
```

It works if I try to print `car_name` but it still overriding the name and if I print `name` it still returns the name of the `user` instead of the `car`.

Is there a way for doing this right?

Comment: And if you add and alias for users.name? It doesn't works?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I realized a mistake on the question, I will edit.

Comment: You have an alias for car.name DB::raw('cars.name as car_name'), I think you can do the same with users.name DB::raw('users.name as user_name'), I don't know about eloquent but it's like an SQL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`select()` clause directly in your query](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects).. no need to use `DB::raw()`:

```
$cars = Cars::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'cars.owner')
            ->select('*','cars.name as car_name')
            ->get();
```

The problem with this is that you will end up with a repeated column as you are asking the DB for everything, plus the field with a new name.  That may not be a problem for you, but might be better to specify explicitly the fields you want to select:

```
$cars = Cars::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'cars.owner')
            ->select('users.name as user_name','cars.name as car_name', 'whatever_else')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do what you want with gets - but you can with select. This should hopefully work:

```
$columns = [
    '*',
    'users.name as user_name',
    'cars.name as car_name'
];

$cars = Cars::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'cars.owner')->select($columns)->get();
```